# Filtering clustered markers on Leaflet.js using slider from nouislider?

Tags: leaflet

I have clustered markers on the map and I am using a library called nouislider for my slider. I am using this to show certain markers based on the range of the distance specified.

I got this working for the markers but no luck on clustered markers. It is removing all my cluster markers rather than filter it. I'm not sure how to approach this.

Here is a link to my code. I can't get the slider to show up on Jfiddle and also got an error on there -"L.geoJson is not a function"

[Jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jt100/r740b3d2/181/)

this is my filter which is working for markers but not for clustered markers, I think the problem is I am not filtering the clustered markers and I am not sure how to do it.

```
        var slider = document.getElementById("slider");

        noUiSlider
          .create(slider, {
            start: [min + 1, max - 1],
            tooltips: true,
            connect: true,
            range: {
              min: min,
              max: max
            }
          })
          .on("slide", function(e) {
            console.log("e", e);
            surfSpotsGeoJSON.eachLayer(function(layer) {
              console.log("layer", layer);
              if (
                parseFloat(layer.feature.properties.distance) >=
                  parseFloat(e[0]) &&
                parseFloat(layer.feature.properties.distance) <=
                  parseFloat(e[1])
              ) {
                layer.addTo(map);
              } else {
                map.removeLayer(layer);
              }
            });
          });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err.message));
  }
```

Comment: Error `L.geoJSON is not a function` is consequence of using Leaflet 0.7. This layer type was not supported at that time. After you include last version of Leaflet 1.5.1, you will also have to get newer version 1.4.1 of MarkerCluster plugin. Then your real debugging can start. For beginning, you will get error that `markersToMap` object/variable is not defined.